# program flow hanging inside inner function

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Really hoping to get an explanation /fix for this issue.  Using Python3 and tkinter.
I have a program window that calls a chain of functions for log in to a database.  One of them calls a toplevel() log in dialog that should return an array / list of values.  The toplevel dialog creates a set of entries that are read by a nested function and values stashed in a global list and then destroys toplevel window. The list is returned by the outer function to an original calling function.
Works great except if this function call originates from a higher level TK dialog.  As is, I have to close out the entire program to get a return from that function.  How do I fix this?  Function listed here
Thanks!

```
# GUI constructor for log in
def login():
    # Create logwin window
    logwin = Toplevel()
    logwin.title("Log In")

    # Called by login() GUI/bsubmit - returns credentials from log in GUI
    def userinfo():
        global carray
        sname=serventry.get()
        lname=lnentry.get()
        pname=passentry.get()
        carray = [sname, lname, pname]
        logwin.destroy()
        print("userinfo() = ", carray)


    # Create GUI
    servlabel = Label(logwin, text="Server Address: ")
    servlabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
    serventry = Entry(logwin)
    serventry.grid(row=0, column=1)
    serventry.focus()

    lnlable = Label(logwin, text="User Name: ")
    lnlable.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5)
    lnentry = Entry(logwin)
    lnentry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=4)

    passlabel = Label(logwin, text="Enter Password: ")
    passlabel.grid(row=2, column=0)
    passentry = Entry(logwin, show="*")
    passentry.grid(row=2, column=1)

    bsubmit = Button(logwin, text="Submit", command=userinfo, default='active')
    bsubmit.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)

    logwin.mainloop()
    print("login() end:", carray)
    return(carray)
```

Comment: Is this the complete code? Firstly, `logwin` is a local variable and cannot be used outside the function, is there any indentation issue while pasting the code here? Please fix it. Secondly, you cannot use `return` outside a function, so that will trigger another error.

Comment: First, the indentation got messed up when pasting.  I've fixed that now.  This is a function in a much larger program.  userinfo() is a child of login(). Return here works because it is part of the login()  function.  Yes, I was working on the assumption that logwin is a local and this is why the nested function userinfo()  so that it can access the graphic widgets.  userinfo() is supposed to return the data collected to the the outer login() function and subsequently back to an original calling program. \

Comment: Where does this lag? or freeze your GUI

Comment: It does not freeze the gui.  It simply does not continue past the nested function.   It destroys the login() dialog and prints the value of carray but does not continue past that point until the main program dialog (not shown) is destroyed.  Note there is one more print at the end of login() before the return that does not occur untill main is killed.

Comment: I'll note that I'm new to this forum and not sure the best way to make the larger program available for review.  This is all part of a much larger program.  Frontend.py calls one of several manager Tk() dialogs which all call the login dialog as needed to supply credentials for calls to mysql.connector.  Was managing this with a text file to store credentials but that was a bad idea for security reasons...

Comment: So your Q is why `print("login() end:", carray)` and  `return(carray)` is not being executed as long as your window is being run?

Comment: That is correct ;-)   I need to be able to pass carray back to another function to log into the database.  The main (root()) Tk dialog does various search and insert/edit functions and each function requires a new instance for mysql.connect(), or that was my understanding.  Thanks!

Comment: In a nutshell, eveything between `Tolevel()` till `mainloop()` will be run as long as the window stays open, when you close the window, the code after the `root.mainloop()` will be executed, also its not necessary to have `mainloop()` for toplevels, get rid of it.. Similar to a loop, as long as you dont exit the loop, you will be inside the loop.

Comment: Hmmm, withoout a mainloop on the toplevel login() dialog it tries to exit the function before the credentials (carray) are collected.  This causes the return variable to not be initialized.  Then when userinfo() gets triggered by bsubmit, there is no handler for the results. Maybe this is just a structuring issue? Will need to study this for a bit... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this one:
I was using logwin.destroy in the inner function userinfo() and for whatever reason this did not allow the function to continue while the main Tk() construct was running.  I then tried placing logwin.quit() on the inner loop and this allowed the function to progress as intended but did not destroy the logwin construct.  Placing logwin.destroy() after the logwin.mainloop() then takes care of this. Data is passed back to my program and life is good.

```
def login():
    # Create logwin window
    logwin = Toplevel(root)
    logwin.title("Log In")

    # Called by login() GUI/bsubmit - returns credentials from log in GUI
    def userinfo():
        global carray
        sname=serventry.get()
        lname=lnentry.get()
        pname=passentry.get()
        carray = [sname, lname, pname]
        logwin.quit()
        print("userinfo() = ", carray)
        return carray
    
    # Create GUI
    servlabel = Label(logwin, text="Server Address: ")
    servlabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
    serventry = Entry(logwin)
    serventry.grid(row=0, column=1)
    serventry.focus()

    lnlable = Label(logwin, text="User Name: ")
    lnlable.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5)
    lnentry = Entry(logwin)
    lnentry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=4)

    passlabel = Label(logwin, text="Enter Password: ")
    passlabel.grid(row=2, column=0)
    passentry = Entry(logwin, show="*")
    passentry.grid(row=2, column=1)

    bsubmit = Button(logwin, text="Submit", command=userinfo, default='active')
    bsubmit.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)

    logwin.bind('<Return>', userinfoalt) # binds alternate credentials function to the return key.
    logwin.mainloop()
    logwin.destroy()
    print("login() end:", carray)
    return(carray)
```